# Replace array of objects with new object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6, splice

I have an array of objects and I would like to replace an object with a new object that has a specific id. My goal is to replace/remove the object where id === 'hotel' with an entirely new object and keep the same index.

Example / Current Code

```
const sampleArray = [{ id: 'price' }, { id: 'hotel1', filters: [] }, { id: 'type' }]

const index = sampleArray.findIndex((obj) => obj.id === 'hotel1') // find index
sampleArray = sampleArray.splice(index, 0) // remove object at this index
sampleArray.splice(index, 0, { id: 'hotel2' }) // attempt to replace with new object ... not working :(
```

Comment: When you use `splice` to delete an item, the second argument should be 1, not 0. Otherwise it has no effect. Also *"not working"* is not a clear problem statement. I suppose you meant that the object **is** added, but the original object was **not** removed.

Comment: How about just assigning to that index?  `sampleArray[index] = { id: 'hotel2' }`

Comment: Why do you call `.splice()` twice? _"The [`splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) method changes the contents of an array by removing or **replacing existing elements** and/or adding new elements in place."_

Comment: _"where id === 'hotel'"_ - There's no such element

Comment: _"not working :("_ -> [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): _"**Describe the problem.** "It doesn't work" isn't descriptive enough to help people understand your problem. Instead, tell other readers what the expected behavior should be. Tell other readers what the exact wording of the error message is, and which line of code is producing it."_

Comment: Got it for next time ;)

Comment: Not "next time". Now -> [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70960330/edit)

Comment: No, next time! @Andreas

Comment: @Andreas - I might be missing some context, but the post provides expected behavior ("_I would like to replace an object with a new object that has a specific id_"), and an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). As far as I can tell, this question meets SO criteria. I'm not sure how multiple paragraphs re-stating the problem would be beneficial.

Comment: @JDB That's definitely not a [mcve] because that script, as-is, would throw a `TypeError`.

Comment: I mean, @Andreas does have a fair point about the bug in your example. It's a good idea to test your code to make sure it actually runs. Bugs are distracting and you are shooting yourself in the foot by leaving them in there. That said, the example uses minimal code to demonstrate the problem, it provides all parts needed to run the code (no libraries or missing function definitions, etc) and it accurately reproduces the problem. This particular minor bug was trivial to see through, but it's a good reminder to test your code in the future.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need the fancy splice logic. Just set the array element and forget it.

```js
const sampleArray = [{ id: 'price' }, { id: 'hotel1', filters: [] }, { id: 'type' }]

const index = sampleArray.findIndex((obj) => obj.id === 'hotel1'); // find index
sampleArray[index] = { id: 'hotel2' }; // replace with new object ... working :)

console.log(JSON.stringify(sampleArray));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `map()` function:

```
const updatedArray = sampleArray.map(item => item.id === 'hotel' ? {...item, id: 'hotel2'} : item);
```

Comment: Not only does this leave the original array intact, it is terribly inefficient.

Answer (score -1):

Another way, replacing an array element by index

```js
const sampleArray = [{ id: 'price' }, { id: 'hotel1', filters: [] }, { id: 'type' }]

const index = sampleArray.findIndex((obj) => obj.id === 'hotel1'); // find index
Object.assign(sampleArray, { [index]: { id: 'hotel2' } }); // replace with new object


console.log(sampleArray);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Wow... that is... definitely one way to do it. This would also work: `Object.assign(sampleArray, new Proxy({}, { get() { return { id: 'hotel2' }; }, ownKeys() { return [""+index] }, getOwnPropertyDescriptor() { return { configurable: true, enumerable: true }; } })); // replace with new object`, but I wouldn't recommend it.